# How to duplicate Web traffic to a to-be-production application, taking care of CSRF tokens, JSF view states and differing session cookies?

Tags: jsf, proxy, csrf, http-proxy, traffic

I want to replicate web traffic from production server to another instance of the application (pre-production env), so that i can verify that any improvements (e.g. performance-wise) that were introduced (and tested on course), remain improvements in the context of production-like load.

(Obviously, something that is clearly a performance improvement during tests, might as well turn out not quite so on the production. For example when trading time vs memory usage.)

There are tools like

- teeproxy (https://serverfault.com/questions/729368/replicating-web-application-traffic-to-another-instance-for-testing, https://github.com/chrislusf/teeproxy/blob/master/teeproxy.go)
- duplicator ([Duplicate TCP traffic with a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247668/duplicate-tcp-traffic-with-a-proxy), https://github.com/agnoster/duplicator)

but they don't seem to address the fact, that the duplicated web traffic will get

- different session cookies
- different CSRF tokens (in my case this is covered by JSF view state ids)

Is there a tool that could do that, automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar concern and opened an issue [here](https://github.com/twitter/diffy/issues/40)

Also since it is an open project I wanted to see if i can inject my own logic.
I am stuck there :- [Adding headers to diffy proxy before multicasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250784/adding-headers-to-diffy-proxy-before-multicasting)

I dont have enough reputation to comment so added an answer

Answer (score -1):

[Twitter's diffy](https://github.com/twitter/diffy) is specialized to duplicate HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find it in their docs nor examples. How does diffy deal with different session cookies or CSRF tokes? It seems that by defaults only the primary instance will have user sessions logged in?